# Question about VS 2010 web application template (html markup)

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010

In the image below, in my markup, the title of the page is "Welcome to My sample Web Site" (not all caps). However, in the split screen, the title is shown in all caps.

The code in CSS is:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #666666;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.header h1
{
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    color:white;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

I want to display the title as I coded in the markup (not all caps).

[image: VS 2010 Sample Template]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try changing `font-variant: small-caps;` to `font-variant: normal;`

Comment: dang that was an easy one. Thanks to all, unfortunately, I can only accept one answer :-(

Answer (score 2):

The line causing the change is in the

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
```

group.

You could change the line:

```
font-variant: small-caps;
```

to be:

```
font-variant: normal;
```

but that would change all of the headers back to normal casing. If you just want to change the title header to normal, add the following to the CSS:

```
#title h1
{
    font-variant: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
h1 {
font-variant: normal;
}
```

Other possible values are, as you've seen, `small-caps` and `inherit`.